# php mysql date comparing with greater than and smaller than operator

Tags: php, mysql, date, compare

i am facing problem with date comparing in my Mysql datebase using php .My date field is in DATETIME and i am using this following query below but it is not returning correct answer please help me ..here is the code

```
"SELECT * FROM record WHERE Dateincident  >=  $from AND Dateincident <=$to";
```

$from and  $to are input got from jquery datepicker.

Comment: Why isn't `$from` quoted? `"SELECT * FROM record WHERE Dateincident BETWEEN '$from' AND '@to'"` -- also, have you checked to ensure both the PHP variable `$from` exists and the MySQL variable `@to` exists?

Comment: yeah both these variable exists

Comment: Can you post the compiled SQL query?

Comment: Is there a reason that `$from` is a php variable and `@to` is a MySQL variable?

Comment: From the comment below the code it looks like it should be `$to`. Getting it straight from the date-picker? Have you consider the format expected by MySQL and sanitization?

Comment: Both are php var sory i made correction

Comment: Post the result of `var_dump($from); echo '-'; var_dump($to)`

Comment: string(10) "2013-06-01" -string(10) "2013-06-26"

Comment: rather than reference $from and $to directly in constructing the SQL, should use the result of mysql_real_escape_string() or your script suffers from SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to put quotes around datetime values

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM record WHERE Dateincident >= '$from' AND Dateincident <= '$to'";
                                                   ^     ^                     ^   ^
```

which is the equivalent of

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM record WHERE Dateincident BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'";
```

Now `$from` and `$to` should be in proper format

```
'YYYY-MM-DD' or 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS'
```

like

```
$from = '2013-06-01';
$to   = '2013-06-26';
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2a8d/2)** demo

**On a side note** consider to use **[prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ)** instead of constructing query strings by concatenating sql statements with values.

Comment: if not using prepared statements, do use mysql_real_escape_string() when substituting publicly-derived variable values in the SQL string.

Answer (score 0):

may be something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM record 
WHERE Dateincident BETWEEN <from> AND <to>
```

I tested it in this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e965/1) and it works.

But it is possible that the problem is not your SQL query, but your php script. SO please try this:

```
$mysqlhost="yourDBHost";
$mysqluser="yourMYSQLUser";
$mysqlpwd="yourMYSQLPass"; 
$mysqldb="yourDataBaseName";
$connection=mysql_connect($mysqlhost, $mysqluser, $mysqlpwd) or die("Connection failed.");

mysql_select_db($mysqldb, $connection) or die("Database could not be selected.");

$query = "SELECT * FROM `record` WHERE `Dateincident` BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."'";
$rescource = mysql_query($query) or die("Error processing query.");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rescource)){
    // do something with each row
}

mysql_close($connection);
```

Comment: provide more information, please. what is the error? the error code?

Comment: using `WHERE BETWEEN` is definitely recommended